# Invert the Laplacian of a 2D fixed grid data array

Tags: python, cdo-climate, nco, metpy, ncl

I want to invert the Laplacian on a 2d fixed grid in python, which was possible to do in `ncl` using the [`ilapsf`](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/ilapsf.shtml) function.  I don't really want to try and do this from scratch using a convolution and thought this would be the bread and butter of [pyngl](https://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/), [metview](https://metview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [metpy](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/index.html), but it seems `ilapsf` didn't make the transfer to python and `metpy` only does the easier Laplacian calculation, rather than solving the inverse Laplacian. I also didn't find anything in `scipy`.

The old code in `ncl` was as simple as this:

```
chi = ilapsF_Wrap(nei,0) # inverse laplace
gradchi = grad_latlon_cfd(chi, chi&latitude, chi&longitude, True, False) # calculate the gradient
```

I managed using the `dv2uv` function in cdo, but it is the fudge of the century, involved conversion to a spectral field and then tricking it by turning the flux convergence into a divergence field, setting up a dummy zero vorticity field and then turning u and v into energy fluxes... (plus the meridional flux does weird things at the poles, which the ncl solution can handle). You would think that there would be a more generic inverse Laplacian available in python (in fact I'm sure there is, I'm just not looking in the right place).

```
from cdo import Cdo
cdo=Cdo()

# convert flux divergence into GG and the spectral G:
cdo.gp2sp(input="-remapcon,T511grid -selvar,nei nei.nc",output="neisp.nc")

# fudge CDO into thinking this is pure divergence (code=155)
cdo.chname("nei,sd",input="neisp.nc",output="tmp_vd.nc")

# make up a zero field for vorticity
cdo.chname("nei,svo",input="-gec,1e36 neisp.nc",output="tmp_vo.nc")

# the result is energy flux, not winds, so we will need to change the output names (and eventually metadata):
cdo.dv2uv(input="-merge tmp_vo.nc tmp_vd.nc",output="tmp_fluxes.nc")
cdo.chname("v,vflux",input="-chname,u,uflux tmp_fluxes.nc",output="fluxes.nc")
```

Comment: I poked around inside the NCL interpreter, and found [the place that ilapsf is implemented](https://github.com/NCAR/ncl/blob/6.6.2/ni/src/lib/nfp/sph2W.c#L3826). It seems to be implemented using a different NCAR library, spherepack. I found some [Python bindings to spherepack](https://github.com/jswhit/pyspharm), but I can't tell if it provides what you need. [This example](https://github.com/jswhit/pyspharm/blob/b913aac7a25495caaa253ab4570f50a398e5639c/examples/twolevel.py#L54) from pyspharm may help you.

Comment: that definitely looks like a good place to start in fact, thanks a lot... I'll take a detailed look later on tonight.